# How navigate from nested fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a fragment that has a FragmentContainerView, and when I try to navigate from a nested fragment, I get an error Navigation action/destination cannot be found from the current destination Destination. When trying to navigate from the fragment in which the FragmentContainerView lies, everything works. How I can fix it ?

```
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="CameraDetailsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

navigation attempt

```
    override fun onEditPressed() {
    //error
    navigate(
        CameraDetailsFragmentDirections.actionCameraDetailsFragmentToAddCameraFragment(model = currentCameraModel)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think it's better to use **navigation graph's** where you navigate to another `navigationGraph` by **including your** `navigationGraph` in the `current one` your using then navigating to the new one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).